# Feature detection of <a ping> (Hyperlink Auditing)

Tags: javascript, dom, browser-feature-detection

The `ping` attribute of the `a` element is used for [hyperlink auditing](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#hyperlink-auditing) - basically when a link is followed each url listed in the attribute is 'pinged' with a HTTP POST.

According to to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=ping) it's supported on all major modern browsers except Firefox ([one day maybe](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=951104)).

How do I detect with JavaScript if the browser supports this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following expression `"ping" in HTMLAnchorElement.prototype` will return `true` if the browser supports the `ping` attribute, `false` otherwise.